# Полная версия сайта на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте, друзья!
Столкнулся с простым вопросом, но не понимаю, как его легче всего решить.
Хочется, чтобы на мобильных устройствах отображалась полная версия сайта, а не кривой "адаптив", подстраивающийся под ширину экрана. Это что, только в табличной верстке можно сделать?
Как это сделать в блочной верстке?

Comment: Нет, потросто фиксируй весь контент и все + убери или не добавляй <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> и все получится

Comment: не факт! как раз если все, как вы говорите, зафиксировать, например, ставим фикс 1000px, то на айпаде ландшафт будет вроде бы все гут, а вот на айпаде-портрет кусок справа шириной 232px уйдет за экран, блондинки начнут переворачивать айпад в поисках отрезаной части))). на айфоне все будет еще печальнее... Как минимум как раз не фикс нужен, а ширина 100%

Comment: резина совсем никак не подойдет, нужны точные величины вроде px
я бы еще использовал grid960 тоже как вариант нормальная штука, только без адаптива она будет скейлится и все будет красиво

Answer (score 1):

Правильное программирование адаптивного сайта ни в коем случае не должна иметь "*кривой адаптив*". Примените viewport: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`. Примените "резиновый/жидкий" макет для стилей. Размечайте стили не статикой, например в пикселях или em, а в процентах, но только там, где это необходимо. Например: width:80%. Если всё-же требуется статическая величина, то употребляйте em вместо px - *[**конвертер**](http://pxtoem.com/)*. **[Инфо Гугл для разработчиков](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/responsive-design?hl=ru)** + **[официальный блог Гугл](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html)**

Answer (score 0):

```
min-width: 1200px; /*здесь ширину основной части*/
```